# PHP is not reading Korean characters from CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file which contains Korean characters which has to be written in oracle database.

When I read the CSV with 'fgetcsv' I don't see the Korean characters instead it looks like:

[image: (image)]

My PHP file header is set to "UTF-8" and the db NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"when I read the CSV"*? Reading doesn't typically show anything so how are you viewing what you read?

Comment: This is always worth reading too ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/how-to-support-utf-8-completely-in-a-web-application (ignore the DB parts)

Comment: I have used this code to read the CSV file and just print them

`code` while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
    
Here i am printing the value 
}

Comment: Code goes in your question, not in the comments. Is your output in an HTML document? If so, is it being delivered with a UTF8 charset and / or with [`<meta charset="utf-8">`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/285036/283366) in the `<head>`? How **exactly** are you *"printing the value"*?

Comment: Yes the output is HTML document. and the meta charset is utf-8. I have opened the CSV file with fgetcsv and putting it in the loop and trying to take each column and print them with echo (to test whether i am getting korean character)

Comment: if youve found the solution, answer your own question and accept it. changing your title to 'solved' doesnt help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Your PHP page should be rendered as UTF-8 character set to view the Korean (in my case) character for that `mb_string` variables has to be set as UTF-8 as follows.

```
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        mb_http_output('UTF-8');
        mb_http_input('UTF-8');
        mb_language('uni');
        mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
        ob_start('mb_output_handler');
```

and then there should be a environment variable has to be placed as follows:

```
        PutEnv("NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8");
```

Finally convert the string to UTF-8 with `mb_convert_encoding`:

```
        mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "EUC-KR");
```

We are done.

Comment: This answer worked great for my own answer, where I was having trouble displaying some korean chars (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40427921/3298930).