# How can I create DOM object from a HTML file in php language?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I want to parsing data from homepage on this [url](http://eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.htm). As you can see this url is HTML file and I read below:

```
// Create a DOM object from a HTML file
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');
```

so I just type a code below

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html('eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.htm');
echo $html->plaintext;
```

The error message is:

> Error message Warning: file_get_contents(eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.ht‌​m): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.27-0\apache2\htdocs\simple_html_dom‌​.php on line 76

what should I do?

Comment: A good DOM parser  is http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: dear Jose, I want extract just text from this homepage (http://eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.htm) but when  implement this php file in server, occuring error message                                                      
Warning: file_get_contents(eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.27-0\apache2\htdocs\simple_html_dom.php on line 76

Comment: (eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.ht‌​m) this link is not url but html file . I read PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual. this manual's contents below  
// Create a DOM object from a HTML file
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');   I think                                                  $html = file_get_html('eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.htm'); this part making Error especially ('eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.htm')

Comment: seems that include of the SimpleHtmlDom library does not function correctly, are you sure that the path is correct? is it in the same folder as your executed php script?

Comment: Dear Elzo, I think that library file does not function correctly. because i have a another php file that related with html dom parser. before i ask this probelm, another php file activate correctly but now this php file cause Error too... this error message                                                     Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.27-0\apache2\htdocs\simple_html_dom.php on line 1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the HTML code using the Snoopy Class (https://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy). Next code displays the HTML code inside of a `<textarea>` tag, then it displays the page itself, copy-paste next code in a PHP file and open it in your browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="ko">
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
require("Snoopy.class.php"); // ◄■■ GET SNOOPY FROM https://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy
$snoopy = new Snoopy;
$snoopy->fetch("http://eecs.kookmin.ac.kr/site/computer/notice.htm");
$html = mb_convert_encoding( $snoopy->results, "UTF-8", "EUC-KR" ); // ◄■■ GET HTML CODE.
echo "<textarea rows='25' cols='80'>$html</textarea>"; // ◄■■ DISPLAY THE HTML.
echo $html; // ◄■■ DISPLAY THE WEBPAGE.
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Snoopy Class is only one file, make sure the file is in the same directory your PHP file is.

Comment: Thank you Jose! your kind answer save me i will try with your method. If i have a problem, may i ask you a question?

Comment: @Hansam, sure, make any question.

Comment: Snoopy is really a dead project, try [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) instead.